# How to hide broken image and showing alt text only in IE 9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Here is the Code:

```
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="../about.aspx">
                                <img class="xyz" src="" 
                                    alt="getit"
                                    title="getit" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

i want only alt text to be displayed when image src is blank .
this is working fine in IE 11 but i see a red cross with alt text in IE 9.

Comment: From the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element): *"The src attribute **must be present**, and **must contain a valid non-empty URL** potentially surrounded by spaces referencing a non-interactive, optionally animated, image resource that is neither paged nor scripted."*

Comment: but in this specific case, i dont have image. Is there any way to achieve what i want i.e. showing only the alt text .

Comment: You'll have to use something other than the `img` tag if your image has no `src`.

Comment: sorry for such a late reply, but yes i changed the tag as suggested by @JamesDonnelly